# How can I copy a *.html file in /dist folder when using vue-cli-service build --target lib?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

While I clearly am no webpack expert, I usually figure/find out what I need to modify in order to achieve what I need. However, I lost more than a day on this one, even though it seems fairly simple:

I want to add an `index.html` to the build, after building, by copy-ing it from a folder.

I tried adding this to `configureWebpack`, in `vue.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  new CopyPlugin([{
    from: 'deploy',
    to: '/',
    force: true,
    copyUnmodified: true
  }])
]
```

(the only file in `deploy` folder is this `index.html`).

I also tried various versions of `chainWebpack`, mostly picked from github discussions, trying to tap into plugins like `html`, `move-index` and `copy`. However, most of what I found on github breaks the build for me.

Not even simple attempts, where I just try to tap and console don't seem to work:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config
    .plugin('html')
    .tap(args => {
      console.log(args);
      return args;
    });
},
```

outputs:

```
Building for production as library (commonjs,umd,umd-min)...[]
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property '__expression' of undefined`
...
at module.exports.toConfig (D:\sgn\www\_g\berwow\BERWoW\Client\RecommenderV2\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:40)
```

---

What I figured out so far:

- CopyPlugin either doesn't work or it has an exception for `.html` files.
- There're are at least two plugins: (`move-index` & `html`) which probably interfere with my copy. I haven't figure out how to push my change to the back of the queue.

I also tried with a `test.html` and I also tried placing a different extension on my file `.txt` and overriding it when copying it, back into `.html`. Most times I end up with errors.

Is there a relatively straight forward way to tap into `vue-cli-serve`'s `build` command and simply copy an `index.html` to the folder?

The build command I'm using is:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name SomeName --inline-css --inline-vue src/main.ts
```

Please note it's a `--target lib` build, which doesn't output an `index.html` into the `dist` folder, but a `demo.html`. So I'd advise testing any solution against a `--target lib` build, as it clearly has a different output than normal builds.

Here's the output of `vue inspect`: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/rkh5ecvd/embedded/js/dark/#JavaScript
and here's the current contents of my `vue.config.js`: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/fou3y4zc/embedded/js/dark/#JavaScript , where `configWebpack` and `chainWebpack` are attempts at addressing/peeking into the above issue.

I'm using `@vue/cli 4.2.3` and `vue 2.6.11` with `webpack 4.42.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way around it, by simply running `npm i copyfiles -D` and adding this bit to the `build` script:

```
 && copyfiles -f ./deploy/* dist/Recommender
```

It's not a proper answer to the problem, it's a way around it. But it works :).

Still interested in how this could be chained to the webpack build script properly.

Comment: Have you found a better answer yet?

Comment: I have done "vue-cli-service build && cp -avr ../lib/ ../wwwroot/js" so i can copy the entire folder

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old issue, but I figured I'd add some more details for anyone still having issues with this in Vue 3.

I was able to achieve a similar output with [vue](https://vuejs.org/) 3.0.0, [@vue/cli-service](https://cli.vuejs.org/) 4.5.0, [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) 4.46.0 and [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/) 6.4.1 using the following configs:

vue.config.js

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

/**
 * @type {import('@vue/cli-service').ProjectOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        // Disable HTML Generation.
        config.plugins.delete("html");
        config.plugins.delete("preload");
        config.plugins.delete("prefetch");

        // Copy all contents of the "static" src directory
        // to the destination's root.
        config.plugin("copy").use(CopyPlugin, [
          {
            patterns: [{ from: "./static", to: "./" }],
          },
        ]);
    },
};
```

npm script:

```sh
vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name app src/main.js
```

Note: the "inline-vue" argument forces embedding Vue into the bundle (see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library).